# Azure DevOps JavaToolInstaller - Can't get jdkDestinationDirectory Right

Tags: java, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My first version (in `azure-pipelines.yml`) targeted the `tempDirectory/bin` folder:

```yaml
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '11'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: LocalDirectory
    jdkFile: "JDK Bin.zip"
    jdkDestinationDirectory: "$(agent.tempDirectory)/bin"
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
```

and I was rewarded with

```
Retrieving the JDK from local path.
Creating destination folder: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_temp\jdk
Extracting file: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\1637\s\JDK Bin.zip
[command]I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_tasks\JavaToolInstaller_c0e0b74f-0931-47c7-ac27-7c5a19456a36\0.151.2\FileExtractor\7zip\7z.exe x -oI:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_temp\jdk "I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\1637\s\JDK Bin.zip"

7-Zip [64] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 8875164 bytes (8668 KiB)

Extracting archive: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\1637\s\JDK Bin.zip
--
Path = I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\1637\s\JDK Bin.zip
Type = zip
Physical Size = 8875164

Everything is Ok

Folders: 1
Files: 121
Size:       21509208
Compressed: 8875164
(node:12092) Warning: Use Cipheriv for counter mode of aes-256-ctr
JAVA_HOME is being set to: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_temp\jdk\bin
JAVA_HOME_11_x64 is being set to: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_temp\jdk\bin
##[error]Directory does not exist: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_temp\jdk\bin\bin
##[error]Directory does not exist: I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_temp\jdk\bin\bin
```

I have no idea where it gets that it should be looking for `\bin\bin` - it looks to me like everything is working as expected

My .zip file has this structure:

```
bin/
- server/
  - somefile.dll
- *lots of dlls*
```

Anyone know where I'm screwing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ##[error]Directory does not exist: I:\Agent-Win-A_work_temp\jdk\bin\bin

The root cause of this issue could be that the `JavaToolInstaller` task hasn't created the correct destination folder.

Based on my test, I could run the task successfully with the same Yaml definition.

I notice that the task will create a destination folder: `xxxx\Agent2\_work\_temp\bin\JAVA_HOME_11_x64_JDK Bin_zip`

[image]

But in your case, it creates the wrong path: `xxx\_work\_temp\jdk`

According to your log,  your are using the `JavaToolInstaller` task version : **0.151.2**. This could be an old task version.  I am using the version **0.177.0**

You could try to navigate to `I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_tasks` and find the folder `JavaToolInstallerxxxx`. Then you could delete it and re-run the pipeline.

The pipeline will download the latest version of the `JavaToolInstaller` task  automatically.

Comment: How can I navigate to the `I:\Agent-Win-A\...` folder?  I don't see a way to get there in the UI.

Comment: @ScottBaker From the log, it seems that you are using the Self-hosted Agent, right? If yes, you can implement this operation on the local machine where the agent is located. Or to confirm this issue, you can also try to use the Microsoft-Hosted Agent(e.g. windows-2019)

Comment: I tried adding a PowerShell task `Remove-Item "I:/Agent-Win-A/_work/_tasks/JavaToolInstaller*" -Force -Recurse` to delete the installer, but when I re-ran the build it failed with `##[error]Could not find a part of the path 'I:\Agent-Win-A\_work\_tasks\JavaToolInstaller_c0e0b74f-0931-47c7-ac27-7c5a19456a36\0.151.2\task.json'.`

Comment: I am using agents defined @ by the enterprise administrators.

Comment: Hi @ScottBaker. If you want to use the Powershell command to remove the task file, you need to create **another pipeline** to run the powershell task. The task install step is  before running the powershell task, if you add the powershell task to the same pipeline, it will delete the latest installed task. Then it will casue this issue.

Comment: Hi @ScottBaker. To follow up, could you please check if  the comment above could give you some help. On the other hand, you can also try to upgrade the agent to the latest version:[2.177.1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/releases/tag/v2.177.1)